# running light functions in concurrently

Tags: clojure

I have light CPU intensive functions that I want to run in parallel. What is the concurrency primitive which I should use ?

Use of agents and futures is not worthwile, as the cost of creating a new thread for these process is not justified.

I want to basically run a few light functions in concurrently, without creating threads. Can i do that ?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Comment: What you may need is co-routines but I am not sure if there exist an implementation for clojure

Comment: Yes having light processes, like in Erlang, would be a good option.

Answer (score 5):

Have you benchmarked?

Agents might well be a good solution anyway, since they use a fixed-size thread pool that gets re-used (so you aren't creating new threads constantly).

I've benchmarked quickly on my machine and can do over million agent calls in 3 seconds:

```
(def ag (agent 0))

(time (dotimes [i 1000000] (send ag inc)))
=> "Elapsed time: 2882.170586 msecs"
```

If agents are still too heavyweight (unlikely?), then you should probably be looking for a way to batch up a group of functions into a single block of work. If you do this, then the overhead of the concurrency primitives will be minimal.

Comment: Mikera thanks for the answer. Nope I haven't benchmarked, as I am penning down the initial design. So the overhead of creating a thread is avoided, however how much overhead is incurred in the context switching ? Any stats (benchmarks :) ) on this ?

Comment: @mikera: You claim "over 3 million agent calls a second", but wasn't it rather "over a third million"? Almost three seconds for a million calls...